# Finding common values in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have 2 df (df1, df2) of different lengths. I want to find values in df2 which is present in df1,then create a new column with boolean values which shows if the values are present. df2 only contains 1 column and less rows than df1. Here is an example of the dfs:

df1:

```
Name  ID    CRITICAL  RATING
win   mrp53  YES        8
lin   mrp54  No         3
mac   0989   YES        8
win   mrp56  YES        8
mac   786    YES        8
win   hte45  YES        8
.
.
```

df2:

```
ID
mrp53
hfy56
dggg4
gfgshh4
```

After the comparison, the df should look like:

```
Name  ID    CRITICAL  RATING  IS_PRESENT
win   mrp53  YES        8       TRUE
lin   mrp54  No         3       FALSE
mac   0989   YES        8       FALSE   
win   mrp56  YES        8       FALSE
```

I am using the below, it's creating the column but the values are wrong. Eg. False for everything:

```
new_df = df1['ID'].assign(IS_PRESENT= df1['ID'].isin(df2['ID]).astype(bool)
```

Any suggestion on how to achieve this?

Comment: Did you try: `df1["IS_PRESENT"] = df1["ID"].isin(df2["ID"])` ? or something similar:  `df1["IS_PRESENT"] = df1["ID"].isin(df2["ID"].tolist())` ?

Answer (score 1):

The following code should suffice.

```py
df1['IS_PRESENT'] = df1['ID'].isin(df2['ID'])
```

`df2['ID']` returns Series.  `isin` accepts Series as its parameter and returns a boolean value based on group membership.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
F = {'id': [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3], 'element': ['a','b','c','d','a','b','b','a','a','b','c','c']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = F)
FF = {'id': [1,5,3,3,4], 'element2': ['aa','ba','ca','da','aa']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = FF)
df['is present'] = df['id'].isin(df2['id'].tolist())
```

Comment: Thanks that works. Reason why it was not working at first was the the column in the second DF was uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use isin function. [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html)

```
df1['IS_PRESENT'] = df1['ID'].isin(df2['ID'].values)
```

[image]